# How to retrieve a GitLab GraphQL's query complexity?

Tags: graphql, gitlab, gitlab-api

Is there any way to retrieve what the query complexity is for a GitLab GraphQL query?

As a comparison, GitHub's GraphQL api has a `rateLimit` object that returns the "`cost`" of a query https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/resource-limitations. Does GitLab have anything similar?

If this capability does not exist, how can one compute the complexity of a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when this was implemented, but you can now query the complexity and limit, as described in the docs and reference https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/#queryquerycomplexity

Example query:

```
{
  queryComplexity {
    limit
    score
  }
}
```

Example response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "queryComplexity": {
      "limit": 300,
      "score": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/index.html#max-query-complexity

There is no way to discover the complexity of a query except by exceeding the limit.

If a query exceeds the complexity limit an error message response will be returned.

In general, each field in a query will add 1 to the complexity score, although this can be higher or lower for particular fields. Sometimes the addition of certain arguments may also increase the complexity of a query.